# If you were to submit a complex frame followed by simple one could they present out of order?

Tags: vulkan

My understanding is that commands within a commandbuffer execute in order. But that command buffers within a queue can execute in any order.

If that's correct, how can you guarantee that frames would not get presented out of sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the specification:

> The processing of the presentation happens in issue order with other queue operations [...] presentation requests sent to a particular queue are always performed in order.